# Divide in pandas sql

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

My pandas query is as follows:

```
ps.sqldf("select  [MCA Governance Entity], [Assessment Unit]  ,fail_cnt  ,pass_cnt ,na_cnt,"
                     "case when fail_cnt <>0 then pass_cnt/(pass_cnt + fail_cnt)*100  else  0 end fail_perc from df7",locals())
```

I am trying to load `fail_perc`  based on case statement, formula used is
(pass_cnt/(pass_cnt + fail_cnt))*100

Independently numerator and denominator produces result but when divided it is giving 0's . Please find attached screen shot

[Image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o38zZ.png)

Comment: Are those integer columns?  If they are integer columns, you'll do an integer division, which will always produce 0.  As a general rule, if you're doing a division and a multiplication, do the multiply first to retain precision:  `pass_cnt * 100 / (pass_cnt + fail_cnt)`.

Comment: Thank you, It worked. I have changed to numeric dataype